# Testing Private Methods (var's) Inside A Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I'm new to unit tests, jasmine, and I was wondering if we could test private methods inside of a function. Here is a code snippet of what I'm trying to do

```
function thisIsTheFunction(...) {
    //Some Code

    var thisIsTheMethod = function () {
        //This Should be tested
    }

    //Someother Code
}
```

I know that we can test `thisIsTheFunction` if it is attached to `this`. But is there a way to test if the method is a private?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the actual logic of the code in thisIsTheMethod then really all you can do is separate that method out into a separate "public" function and test it as its own unit. (bearing in mind that if you wanted to test the logic if the inner function during a test of the outer function then this is an integration test, not a unit test)

However if you want to test the behaviour of your outer function with respect to the inner one, one approach you can take to this, is to allow the caller to pass a callback for the implementation of thisIsTheMethod as part of parameters to the "constructor" of thisIsTheFunction.

This then allows you to "inject" a callback that you define inside your test function so that you can test how thisIstheFunction behaves in terms of does it invoke thisIsTheMethod when it's supposed to, etc.